# What is an efficient way of iterating through a list according to its distinct values?

Tags: c#, linq

```
string sStoreStockFeed = "";
string sSeparator = "";

var distinctStoreIDList = skuStoreStockLevels.Select(x => x.Item1).Distinct();

    foreach (var storeID in distinctStoreIDList)
    {
        foreach (var item in skuStoreStockLevels)
        {
            if (item.Item1 == storeID)
            {
               // add this one to a job for this store
                       sStoreStockFeed += sSeparator + item.Item1.ToString() + "," + item.Item2.ToString() + "," + item.Item3.ToString();
                       sSeparator = "|";
            }
        }
      // some code to process the string before moving on
      sStoreStockFeed = "";
      sSeparator = "";
    }
```

In the above code snippet skuStoreStockLevels just happens to be a List of type Tuple and Item1 is the StoreID.  having got a distinct list it then iterates through the (non-distinct) list to get every applicable item.  The inefficiency is that the (big) inner list is iterated throuh repeatedly for each distinct item (StoreID).

Comment: Make a map `storeID -> job`, and iterate once through the list. If the `storeID` is not yet in the map, add it with a new job. otherwise add the store to the job for its `storeID`. - Oh, and this looks much like C#, not C, so I retagged it.

Comment: Your sSeparator seems to be acting strange, is this on purpose.  I suspect that it will be very hard to read the result in sStoreStockFeed afterward.  You could end up with something like this: A,2,3|A,4,5B,1,2C,3,4|C,6,7...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: pure LINQ solution. This will give you list of strings, created for each group of items.

```
var query = skuStoreStockLevel.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                .Select(g => g.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                         (sb, x) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1},{2},{3}", sSeparator, x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3),
                                         (sb) => sb.ToString()));

foreach(var feed in query)
    // some code to process the string before moving on
```

Also there are other options - ordering of sequence. Equal items will follow one after another.

```
int storeID = -1;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in skuStoreStockLevel.OrderBy(x => x.Item1))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1},{2},{3}", sSeparator, item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);
    if (item.Item1 != storeID)
    {
        // some code to process the string before moving on
        storeID = item.Item1;
    }       
}
```

Or you can use grouping

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var storeGroup in skuStoreStockLevel.GroupBy(x => x.Item1))
{
    foreach (var item in storeGroup)
          builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1},{2},{3}", sSeparator, item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);        

    // some code to process the string before moving on
}
```

And, of course, it's better to use `StringBuilder` for creating strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) which will build you a list of grouped items:

```
string sStoreStockFeed = "";
string sSeparator = "";

var itemsByStore = skuStoreStockLevels.GroupBy(x => x.Item1);
foreach (var storeItems in itemsByStore )
{
    // storeItems.Key is the storeId, that is x.Item1
    foreach(var item in storeItems)
    {
        sStoreStockFeed += sSeparator + item.Item1.ToString() + "," + item.Item2.ToString() + "," + item.Item3.ToString();
        sSeparator = "|";
    }

     // some code to process the string before moving on
    sStoreStockFeed = "";
    sSeparator = "";
}
```